# Show that the sum can be written as:

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation

How can the left side be expressed as the right one?

$$\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{(2n)^2}=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N\cup \{0\}}} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, you should notice that the three series converge. Then $\mathbb{N}=(2\mathbb{N})\sqcup (2\mathbb{N}-1)$, with your $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $\{n^2:n\in\Bbb N$ is the set of all positive squares; $\{(2n)^2:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is the set of all even positive squares; and $\{(2n+1)^2:n\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}\}$ is the set of all odd positive squares. Every integer is either odd or even (and not both!).

Comment: That's a pretty big hint :)

Comment: I've already noticed that but I'm looking for a derivation by expanding the left side with $(n+1)$ into the sums. Thanks though!

Comment: @John: I’m not sure what you mean by ‘expanding ... sums’. (I also rather wonder why you want to pass up the easy argument!)

Comment: @Brian I mean expressing the sums at $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ and then deriving the right side. I'm passing the easy argument because I'm interested in the derivation itself.

Comment: @John: Do you mean rewriting the lefthand side as $$\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\frac1{(n+1)^2}-\frac1{(2(n+1))^2}\right)$$ or the like and somehow manipulating it to get the righthand side? If you could do that, you could similarly manipulate the given lefthand side into $$\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac1{(2n-1)^2}\;,$$ so the index shift serves no real purpose.

Comment: @Brian Correct, I am looking for a manipulation of any of the two sides by writing them via an index shift.